moderncv doesn’t allow links
I have an issue where when I use a link in section as follows -
\section {Test}{some test data. \href {https://google.com}{This is google and you can visit it here.}}

The link doesn’t seem to work.
However when I use it in tables, it works. It also works in the above if I wrap the text in \underline. But in this case the text overflows from the document.
Edit -
Here's the code that I'm working with -
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, CMU-Serif]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.915]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\name{X}{Y}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-16mm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}

\faMobile \enspace+99999999 & \enspace \faAt \enspace \color{cyan}\href{mailto:xyz@gmail.com}{xyz@gmail.com} \enspace & \faHome \enspace test, test \\ \faLinkedin \enspace \color{cyan} \href{https://ie.linkedin.com/in/test}{in/test}     
\end{tabular}   
\end{center}

\section{Professional Summary}
{\color{cyan} \href{https://google.com} {This is google}}

\end{document}

In the above code, the links work when they are inside the tabular wrap, but not when they are in the section wrap.

make a small but complete example that can be used to test your issue.

Thanks for the input. I have updated it above.

Try adding \usepackage{hyperref}.

the google link works fine here. Show your log-file.
